# Can you initialise in the class and in the constructor and is that correct?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Considering the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

class tester
{
public:
    tester(){}
    explicit tester(double val) : 
        m_a(val) // I assume this now overwrites the "default" initialise value?
    {}
    double m_a {1.123}; // Default constructor value?
};


int main()
{
    tester t1;
    tester t2(2.456);

    std::cout << "t1:" << t1.m_a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t2:" << t2.m_a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, can you have both the initialise value in the class and in the constructor body? - how does the compiler resolve this? It appears that the constructor wins since the output of this program is:

```
t1:1.123
t2:2.456
```

Comment: The code you show is fine, and "I assume this now overwrites the "default" initialise value?" is correct.

Comment: thank you - I linked the post to the suggested question that also has the answer I was looking for : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization),

> Through a *default member initializer*, which is a brace or equals [initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) included in the member declaration and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.
>
> If a member has a default member initializer and also appears in the member initialization list in a constructor, the default member initializer is ignored for that constructor.

In the default constructor `m_a` is not mentioned in member initializer list, then it will be initialized by the default member initializer as `1.123`. In `tester::tester(double)` `m_a` will be initialized by the member initializer list as the argument `val`.